Edit data in csv file with java
I am working on a private project that I need to write some data in a CSV file and edit it if needed. When I write the data, everything works fine, but when I try to edit some data in the file I find some problems. When I tried to look for solutions, mostly were to make a temp.csv that loads all the data in the CSV file and edit what's needed and then rename it for the first file. This will be bad if there was a lot of data in the file, too much CPU and memory usage and time spending.
To make the problem clearer my project is focused on booking cars when I register any new car a set the isBooked instance in the car to false as it isn't booked. The problem lies when I book a car in another class which books a car add it to the booked cars db which is also a csv file with additional variables and sets the booked instance as true. But here lies the problem it only sets it in the memory and the file db stays the same.
Here is an exemple of what I am trying to do:
Here is the Car class:
public class Car {
    private String company;
    private String model;
    private boolean isBooked;
    private String color;
    public Car(String company,
               String model,
               String color) {
        this.company = company;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        isBooked=false;
    }

}
and here is the csv file:
Toyota,Camry,Blue,false
Toyota,Supra,White,false
Audi,Rs6,Black,false
Honda,Civic,Silver,false
BMW,3 Series,Black,false

What i want is to create a method which will be in another class named Bookings that takes a car and books it the problem is when i try to book it and change the isBooked to false with a setter in Car it only change it in the memory and csv file stays the same.
I want to edit the false part in the csv file to be true when it is booked without creating new file and copying all the data to it with the change.
Since I am still a beginner in Java, I think it's better to not use any data structures and work with just arrays.
Is there any solution so that I will edit my data without deleting and writing new file?

when i try to edit some data in the file i find some problems what is your exact problem? any (java-)exceptions/errors?

What kind of editing do you want to do? Do you want to insert data into the CSV file? Do you want to delete data from the file? Or do you want to change existing data?

Since I am still a beginner in Java, I think it's better to not use any data structures and work with just arrays. That will be fine, as long as all you want to do is change existing data, i.e. no deletion of data (beyond setting fields to empty) nor adding data. Why? Arrays are fixed size containers. Is that the case for your requirements?

i am working on a car booking system when a register a car in the data is sets the booked variable as false and when i book a car i want to edit the booked variable in the csv file to true

Well that limited functionality would be OK for an array then, though I wouldn't recommend it as it puts that limit (unnecessarily) onto the functionality

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It would be a good thing to post an example file

To make things simple, you might do your own csv parsing since your file seems simple. This would work: List<String> carFile = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("cars.csv"));List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();for (String carText : carFile) {cars.add(new Car(carText.split("\\s*,\\s*")));}System.out.println(cars); You would give Car a ctor that takes String[] as a parameter. You can now changed isBooked in any instance and then write the file out again in a inverse version of the above

In the code you provided you didn't write the changes to the file

In the code you provided you didn't write the changes to the file No. I mentioned you needed to do that

Make Car::toString produce CSV (perfectly reasonable) and saving becomes dead easy

A text file is written as a series of bytes (commonly octets).
The word “series” is crucial here. One byte follows another, which follows another, and so on. Imagine a Conga Line of bytes.
Besides appending, the only edit you can make is to replace text. And even that would be limited to replacing a stretch of the very same number of bytes. In most character encodings, various characters differ in the number of bytes need to represent them. This means even if you want to replace a number of characters with the same number of replacement characters, they may not fit in the written file if a different number of bytes is used in their representation.
That is why you saw tutorials on writing a new file to replace the old file rather than editing in place.

If you are frequently editing very large text files as a way of managing data, I’d suggest it’s time to revisit the architecture of your app.
Frequently changes to parts of large amounts of data are generally best managed by a relational database management system. A database engine is highly optimized for editing and replacing rows of data.
If you want to keep the data local with your Java app, I would suggest using an embedded database engine written in pure Java. Choices include H2 Database Engine, Apache Derby, and more.

If you are just noodling around for fun and learning, then I would recommend forgetting about writing data to storage for now.
Instead work with data in memory. Grow your knowledge about data structures beyond mere arrays. The Java Collections Framework is easy to comprehend, and generally easy to use. See the tutorials provided by Oracle, and by Baeldung.com, free of cost. Search Stack Overflow for many examples of using those classes. Seeing their use in action is the fastest way to grasp the basics.
Eventually, you may want to explore even more collections and data structures provided in libraries such as Google Guava and Eclipse Collections.

Thank you for your answer as it opened my mind to why this is hard to do.
The characters I want to change are simple from false to true or from true to false so that is why I am asking if there is a more simple solution then deleting and copying.
And as for the db choice as I am still learning I still use just normal files when I learn about databases I will definitely take your recommendation of db.
I thank you once again for the explanation.

@user24778581 (a) You should have explained the nature of your edits in your Question. (b) Notice that “true” and “false” have a different number of characters, and a different number of bytes in every character encoding. So even that “simple” case is not so simple.
